# How to use Parcelable and onClickListeners?

Tags: android, json, parcelable

I've been reading up on Parcelables and the more I read the more I'm getting confused about it.

What I'm trying to is the following

1. Hook up to an external API to get JSON data (currently working).
2. I'm parsing the JSON objects just fine into strings that I place in a HashMap.  I'm using a ListView to display the data which is scrollable (currently working)
3. I've setup an onClickListener which sets up a new intent (currently working)
4. Here's where I'm getting confused - my goal is to allow the user to click on an item in the Listview that will take them to a new screen with more detail information about the item they clicked.

Questions to point number 4:

1. Do I use a Parcelable class to pass in JSON object into the intent?  Is it the best option in my case?
2. If Parcelable is the right choice, would I create a new class that implements Parcelables for the JSON Object to be passed in?  I guess I'm really not sure how to proceed.  All the examples I've seen just have a few strings that they pass into the writeToParcel() method.  Not sure how that translates to objects with multiple properties.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to pass data to the next activity, which way is best for you depends somewhat on how complicated your data is.  Some options:

`Parcelable` is just an efficient method of passing complex objects.  If you go this route, then yes you would create a new object that implements `Parcelable`.  Your write method can be as complicated as is necessary.  If you have a complex object tree, just make each of the objects implement `Parcelable` and defer to that object's `writeToParsel` method to write out that portion of the object tree.

A simpler, but less efficient method is to just have all of your objects implement `Serializable`.  There the serializing and deserializing is done for you, but it is noticeably slower than a `Parcelable` implementation.

If your activity only needs a few bits of primitive information, you can also just pass those each as their own extra.

Finally, you could make use of your `Application` class extension or some other singleton to store the complex data structure, and just pass the new `Activity` the little bit of information it needs to look up the rest of the data.  This reduces the amount of data that you need to pass around, and might help you work around the issues with Activities being started and stopped.